# How to display a user profile pics while the user is logged in php?

Tags: php

I have successfully created a form that submits data and a picture of a user into my online folder and the path directory stored in the database.
My question is this how do I get users to see their picture once they are logged in?

Well Guys thanks for everything but still not getting right here is all my code

**Sign Up**

```
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<style type="text/css">
<!--
#apDiv1 {
    position:absolute;
    width:328px;
    height:216px;
    z-index:1;
    left: 347px;
    top: 111px;
}
-->
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div id="apDiv1">
<form method="post" action="logon.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <table width="332" height="210" border="0">
    <tr>
      <td width="155">Email</td>
      <td width="167"><input type="text" name="email" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Username</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="username" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Password</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="password"  /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Upload Passport</td>
      <td><label>
        <input type="file" name="photo"  />
      </label></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td><label>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Sign Up" />
      </label></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  </form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Logon.php**

```
<?php
include('connection.php');
if (!isset($_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'])) {
    echo "";
    }else{
    $file=$_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'];
    $image= addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['photo']['tmp_name']));
    $image_name= addslashes($_FILES['photo']['name']);

            move_uploaded_file($_FILES["photo"]["tmp_name"],"photos/" . $_FILES["photo"]["name"]);

            $email=$_POST['email'];
            $username=$_POST['username'];
            $password=$_POST['password'];
            $photo="photos/" . $_FILES["photo"]["name"];

            $save=mysql_query("INSERT INTO info (id, email, user_name, password,  photo) VALUES ('','$email','$username','$password','$photo')");
            /* Redirect visitor to the thank you page */
echo '<script language="javascript">alert("Registration Succesful....")</script>';
echo '<script language="javascript">window.location = "index.php"</script>';
            exit();                 
    }
?>
```

**Index.php**

```
<?php
include('login.php'); // Includes Login Script
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<style type="text/css">
<!--
#apDiv1 {
    position:absolute;
    width:391px;
    height:178px;
    z-index:1;
    left: 334px;
    top: 166px;
}
#apDiv2 {
    position:absolute;
    width:259px;
    height:115px;
    z-index:1;
    left: 380px;
    top: 137px;
}
-->
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div id="apDiv2">
<form method="POST" action="">
  <table width="260" height="88" border="0">
    <tr>
      <td width="131">Username</td>
      <td width="119"><label>
        <input type="text" name="username" />
      </label></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Password</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="password" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td><label>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
      </label></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <table width="259" border="0">
    <tr>
      <td align="center"><a href="signup.html">Sign Up</a></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  </form>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**login.php**

```
<?php
session_start(); // Starting Session
$error=''; // Variable To Store Error Message
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
if (empty($_POST['username']) || empty($_POST['password'])) {
$error = "User ID or Password is invalid";
}
else
{
// Define $username and $password
$username=$_POST['username'];
$password=$_POST['password'];
// To protect MySQL injection for Security purpose
$username = stripslashes($username);
$password = stripslashes($password);

// Establishing Connection with Server by passing server_name, user_id and password as a parameter
$connection = @mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
// Selecting Database
$db = mysql_select_db("lesson", $connection);
// SQL query to fetch information of registerd users and finds user match.
$query = mysql_query("select * from info where password='$password' AND user_name='$username'", $connection);
$rows = mysql_num_rows($query);
if ($rows == 1) {
$_SESSION['login_user']=$username; // Initializing Session
header("location: customer_login.php"); // Redirecting To Other Page
} else {
$error = "User ID or Password is invalid";
}
mysql_close($connection); // Closing Connection
}
}
?>
```

**customer_login.php**

```
<?php
include('session_connect.php');
?>
<html>
<body>
<style type="text/css">
<!--
#apDiv1 {
    position:absolute;
    width:259px;
    height:173px;
    z-index:1;
    left: 25px;
    top: 92px;
}
-->
</style>
<div id="apDiv1">
  <p>Email: <?php echo $email; ?> </p>
  <p>Username: <?php echo $username; ?> </p>
  <p>Password: <?php echo $password; ?> </p>
  <p>Passport: <?php echo $photo; ?> </p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**session_connect.php**

```
<?php
// Establishing Connection with Server by passing server_name, user_id and password as a parameter
$connection = @mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
// Selecting Database
$db = mysql_select_db("lesson", $connection);
session_start();// Starting Session
// Storing Session
$user_check=$_SESSION['login_user'];
// SQL Query To Fetch Complete Information Of User
$ses_sql=mysql_query("select * from info where user_name='$user_check'", $connection);
$row=mysql_fetch_array($ses_sql);
$login_session =$row['user_name'];

    $email = $row['email'];//." ".$row['vLastName'];
    $username = $row['user_name'];
    $password = $row['password'];
    $photo = $row['photo'];
if(!isset($login_session)){
mysql_close($connection); // Closing Connection
header('Location: index.php'); // Redirecting To Home Page
}
?>
```

Instead the above code shows me the pathway in the database i want the actual image to show...thank you

Comment: Get the path to the image out of the database and place it in a img tag

Comment: use image location path as image src attribute

Comment: What have you tried so far? StackOverflow is for getting answers to specific questions, not a place to find for someone who will do the research and coding for you.

Comment: Fetch those data and put the path directory into the `<img>` src attribute. `<img src="<?php echo $row['path']; ?>">`

Comment: thanks everyone it worked.. i appreciate logan wayne.. but kudos to you all

Answer (score 0):

When you store the Image path in the database, there must be a reference (Foreign key or similar) to the corresponding user.

Now, when the user loggs in, you check the table, where your image paths are declared for the specific user:

```
SELECT imgpath FROM imgpathstable WHERE userid = $loggedInUser["id"]
```

and then you can display an img tag with:

```
<?php
echo "<img href='$imgPath' ...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    <?php
    if(isset($_SESSION['Anyone']))
{
 ?>  
  <img src="<?php echo image path ?>"/>

  <?php                     
    }
    ?>
```